# Next js | how to dynamically update static folder content over CDN ? i am using assetPrefix in next.config

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cdn

i am working on a next js application , right now static content is being served from `.next/static` folder i want to serve static js and css and other file which are there in `.next/static` folder via a `CDN`  for that in my config `next.config.js` i have added

```
module.exports={
    assetPrefix:"https://myTestCDN.com"
}
```

[as per official Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix)

as per the docs user have to upload his .next/static folder content to CDN

my question is how can i update my static content over this cdn every time my application being built

if i built my app locally and transfer content over cdn it would not work because on deployment the build will be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i am able to achieve this, there are two ways to add content to `CDN` so that it could be delivered on our site one is we manually add content which needs to be delivered on `CDN` another is we just add our site link as `origin url` in  `CDN config` , then CDN will itself take the static content from our site and it will be served via `CDN`